# Jquery function undefined when logged in

Tags: safecracker, jquery, ee

I am working on development of a web app where users can use a Channel:form to submit/edit entries. I am Using [mmenu](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/) for off-canvas menu. I had it working and then it stopped, reporting that function is undefined. After hours of debugging found out it works when not logged in to EE. However in order to add/edit entries, I need the visitor to be logged in. Is this a Channel:form problem/error? Anyone know of a work around?

Comment: Try doing a text compare of the html output of the form page when logged in vs when logged out. Probably something to do with script load orders.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I was loading my own JQuery in the head and the Channel form was loading a copy too. I hadn't seen include_jquery option in the Docs before, just one for include_assets (which I thought included jquerey). So once I set include_jquery="no", everything worked!